# Cython Buffer types only allowed as function local variables

Tags: python, numpy, cython, numpy-ndarray

I create a function that take x, y, batch size as input and yield mini batch as output with cython to sped up the process.

```py
import numpy as np
cimport cython
cimport numpy as np

ctypedef np.float64_t DTYPE_t

@cython.boundscheck(False)
def create_mini_batches(np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] X, np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] y, int batch_size):
    
    cdef int m
    cdef double num_of_batch
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] shuffle_X
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] shuffle_y
    cdef int permutation

    X, y = X.T, y.T

    m = X.shape[0]
    num_of_batch = m // batch_size

    permutation = list(np.random.permutation(m))
    shuffle_X = X[permutation, :]
    shuffle_y = y[permutation, :]

    for t in range(num_of_batch):
        mini_x = shuffle_X[t * batch_size: (t + 1) * batch_size, :]
        mini_y = shuffle_y[t * batch_size: (t + 1) * batch_size, :]
        yield (mini_x.T, mini_y.T)
    
    if m % batch_size != 0:
        mini_x = shuffle_X[m // batch_size * batch_size: , :]
        mini_y = shuffle_y[m // batch_size * batch_size: , :]
        yield (mini_x.T, mini_y.T)
```

When I compile the program with this code `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` the following error showed up.

```py
@cython.boundscheck(False)
def create_mini_batches(np.ndarray\[DTYPE_t, ndim=2\] X, np.ndarray\[DTYPE_t, ndim=2\] y, int batch_size):
                       ^

test.pyx:8:24: Buffer types only allowed as function local variables
```

Can someone help me how to solved the error and why it is a error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a sightly confusing error message in this case but you're getting it because it's a generator rather than a function. This means that Cython has to create an internal data structure to hold the generator state while it works.

Typed Numpy array variables (e.g. `np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2]`) were implemented in a way where it's very hard to handle their reference counting correctly. Therefore Cython can only handle them as variables in a regular function. It cannot store them in a class, and thus cannot use them in a generator.

To solve it your either need to drop the typing, or you should switch to the more recent [typed memoryviews](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html) which were designed better so don't have this limitation.

Comment: Hooray, you solved it thanks. Sorry I can't upvote this as my reputation too low 